# kendo chart show dates in dd/MM/yyyy on y axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am working on angular js application and implementing kendo chart, where I want to show dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` on y axis in kendo chart, like below image,
I could not find any solution yet. 
Please provide me sample code or plunker link for this

[image]

Following are sample code

HTML page

```
<div kendo-chart
                 k-legend="{ position: 'top' }"
                 k-series-defaults="model.graphSettings"
                 k-series="[
                                 { field: 'value', name: 'Budget BaseLine' },
                                 { field: 'value1', name: 'Budget Real' }]"
                 k-data-source="model.chartDataSource1"
                 k-category-axis="{labels:{rotation:-45}, title:{text: 'Budget Type'}}"
                    k-value-axis="{title:{text:'Date'}}"
                 k-rebind="model.chartDataSource1"
                 k-tooltip="{visible: true, template: '#= category #: #= value#'}"
                 style="height: 300px;">
            </div>
```

angular js Controller

```
 scope.model.graphSettings = {
            type: 'column'
        };
 var obj = [];
        obj.push({
            category: "Category 1",
            value: new Date(),
            value1: new Date(),

        }, {
            category: "Category 2",
            value: new Date(),
            value1: new Date(),

        })

        scope.model.chartDataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: obj
        });
```

Comment: that graph doesnt make sense to me...

Comment: instead you should provide sample code or plunker of what you have done

Comment: i have updated graph, prev one was wrong chart

Comment: Show us the code and data used to generate the chart.

Comment: I have added code, will you please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange that you have dates on the Y-axis - usually dates are on the X-axis.

To achieve what you have shown in the image you need to add a `labels` section with a template definition to your `valueAxis` options of the chart widget. Here's an example:

```
<div kendo-chart
    k-legend="{ position: 'top' }"
    k-series-defaults="model.graphSettings"
    k-series="[{ field: 'value', name: 'Budget BaseLine' },
               { field: 'value1', name: 'Budget Real' }]"
    k-data-source="model.chartDataSource1"
    k-category-axis="{labels:{rotation:-45}, title:{text: 'Budget Type'}}"
    k-value-axis="{title:{text:'Date'}, labels: {template: '#= kendo.toString(new Date(value),\'dd/MM/yyyy\') #'}}"
    k-rebind="model.chartDataSource1"
    k-tooltip="{visible: true, template: '#= category #: #= value#'}"
                 style="height: 300px;">
</div>
```

This assumes that your dates are in a format which could be parsed by the JavaScript date parser, as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Add your code to the question and explain why it didn't work - what were the results? Was there an error?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be with single quotes: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'

Comment: date is not properly displaying , it is showing like 01011970 , 04051976

Comment: You have some extra characters in there. Get rid of the "ss".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142163/discussion-between-kushal-pawar-and-orilux).

Comment: i have made correction there, but after that i am not getting proper date format, it is showing like 01011970 , 04051976

Comment: I put together a Dojo, which produces a working example of what you are trying to achieve: http://dojo.telerik.com/icECo

Comment: yes done , but date is starting from 1970, and bars will always show on same level, so it is possible to change start date or is it possible to set nearest date of start date?

Comment: The starting date depends on your data. In the example no dates are specified, which is why it all starts at 1970. Here's another example with specified dates: http://dojo.telerik.com/icECo/2